# How would you get all the counted variables in post request

Tags: php, post

I can't figure this one out.

There is a form which sends me the following post request:

Sometimes it is

```
$_POST['length'];
$_POST['length1'];
```

And the other times it is

```
$_POST['length'];
$_POST['length1'];
$_POST['length2'];
```

I have no control how many there will be.

How would you get all the counted lengths and maybe put them in an array?

Comment: You already have them in the $_POST array.

Comment: Yes but there are more in the $_POST not only length

Comment: answer given below, and if that doesn't work, then your form's element(s) isn't properly setup and that's unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop in your `$_POST` array and check if key contains `lenght` with [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function, if so you can put in a new array

```
$array = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if (strpos($key, 'length') !== false) {
        $array[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also get all elements where the key is `xlength` or `whatlengthever`.

Comment: And also, `$value` is undefined.

Comment: @Narf Thanks, my bad